# Percent Rank and Curved Grading in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-drive

I am trying to design a gradebook for a class which follows relative grading. Relative grading here means 30% As, 40% Bs, 30% C and lower.  In a class of 11, for example, 3 students will get As, 5 will get Bs, and 3 will get C or lower.

Students will initially receive a normal percentage grade for total coursework (0-100% <- I already have this calculated out with proper functions and formula). But, **what I want to know is how can I rank them, and then based on the number of students and relative grading percentages, assign their rank the proper grade?**

I have already used =PercentRank to rank them with a percentage, but not sure how to transform that percentage into a curved distribution of grades.

I have included the grading book I am using, which is based off of Vertex42's.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqvTp4ajjRSUdDhZT1hFSkRQRXUtQ1AwWnR6bFRUT0E&usp=sharing

Comment: Once the students are ranked from 1 to 11.  A simple equation will work here.  'IF(Rank/11<.3, "A", Rank/11<.7, "B", "C"))'

Answer (score 1):

I updated your GoogleSpreadsheet with the formula in column Q and R. The formulae are as follow:

```
=rank(P12,$P$12:$P$22,0)
```

To get the ranking and:

```
=if(Q12<large($Q$12:$Q$22,1)*0.3,"A",if(Q12<large($Q$12:$Q$22,1)*0.7,"B","C"))
```

To get the grades.

EDIT: Forgot about MAX, which is shorter than LARGE:

```
=IF(Q12<MAX($Q$12:$Q$22)*0.3,"A",IF(Q12<MAX($Q$12:$Q$22)*0.7,"B","C"))
```